# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text' Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to read a file with python and get each line as a parameter for a function. I've got a AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text' error and I don't understand how to fix it. Here is my code

```
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


file = open("applications.txt","r")
appArray = file.readlines()


def app_metadata(app_link):
    url = 'https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=' + app_link
    response = get(url)
    html_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    print(html_soup.find(class_="AHFaub").text)


#print (appArray[0])
#print(type(appArray[0]))
#print(type("com.codebrewgames.pocketcitygame"))
app_metadata(appArray[2])
```

Comment: The only plausible explanations here are that `response` is `None` or `html_soup.find(class_="AHFaub")` is returning `None`.

Comment: Please always include the complete error traceback in your questions.

Comment: please edit your queation and provide applications.txt file

Comment: @g.d.d.c pointed out the plausible explanations.  Of those the the `html-soup.find(class_="AHFaub")` is almost definitely the cause and returning a `None`.

Comment: On a separate note, the resource file `applications.txt` is never closed.  Make sure you do a file.close() to release the resource.  Even better would be to use a `with` clause to make sure the file is closed. e.g. `with open('applications.txt', 'r') as fin:  appArray=fin.readlines()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
appArray = [line.rstrip() for line in open('applications.txt')]
```

There a newline at the end of the each string. Readlines returns each line string with a newline character at the end. And the requests takes the appId with the newline. Like "com.android.chrome\n" instead "com.android.chrome".

Answer (score 0):

The following line is the source of your error:

```
print(html_soup.find(class_="AHFaub").text)
```

The `html_soup.find(class_="AHFaub")` fails to find the desired section when parsing the response and thus returns `None`.  One fix would be the following:

```
result = html_soup.find(class_="AHFaub")
if result:
    print(result.text)
```

This checks to see if there was a valid result before trying to print.  This is considered a LBYL (look before you leap) approach.

A more pythonic way is to follow an EAFP (easier to ask forgiveness than permission) approach as follows:

```
try:
    print(html_soup.find(class_="AHFaub").text)
except AttributeError:
    print('Failed to parse url: {}'.format(url))
```

This method tries to do the print and if it fails due to an `AttributeError` it will skip it and execute whatever code follows in the `except` block.